# jQuery keeps failing when trying to call a controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a controller action in ASP.Net MVC 5 from a jQuery ajax method. Everything seems to be in place and correct, however my ajax keeps failing. The error return keeps presenting itself and my page does not refresh. However, my controller does get hit. If I set a break point in the C# code under the specific action I am trying to access all goes according to plan.

Yet still the ajax returns an error and the page is never redirected to.

Here is my jQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.searchbox').on('search', function () {
            if ($(this).val() == undefined || $(this).val() == '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '@Url.Action("Index","Company")',
                    error: function () { alert('error'); }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Any suggestions? I can post more code if need be. I am using a search input type and this fires when I clear the search box.

Thanks for any help I get!

Here is the controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(Int32? resultsPerPage, Int32? startingIndex, Int32? currentPage, String searchExpression)
    {
        List<ProspectModel> prospects = ProspectManager.LoadProspects(searchExpression);

        resultsPerPage = resultsPerPage ?? 25;
        startingIndex = startingIndex ?? 0;
        currentPage = currentPage ?? 1;

        if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchExpression))
        {
            ViewBag.Pages = 0;
            ViewBag.TotalRecords = prospects.Count;
            ViewBag.CurrentIndex = 0;
            ViewBag.ResultsPerPage = resultsPerPage;
            ViewBag.CurrentPage = 1;
            ViewBag.LastPageStartingIndex = 1;
            ViewBag.SearchExpression = searchExpression;
            return View(prospects);
        }

        List<ProspectModel> model = prospects.GetRange((Int32)startingIndex, (Int32)resultsPerPage);

        ViewBag.TotalRecords = prospects.Count;
        ViewBag.Pages = (prospects.Count / resultsPerPage) + ((prospects.Count / resultsPerPage) % 2 != 0 ? 1 : 0);
        ViewBag.CurrentIndex = startingIndex + resultsPerPage;
        ViewBag.ResultsPerPage = resultsPerPage;
        ViewBag.CurrentPage = currentPage;
        ViewBag.LastPageStartingIndex = ((prospects.Count / resultsPerPage) % 2 == 0 ? prospects.Count - resultsPerPage : prospects.Count  - ((prospects.Count / resultsPerPage) % 25));
        ViewBag.SearchExpression = null;

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: What does error messages say? Can you show your controller action?

Comment: `contentType` doesn't make sense. You're not sending any data, and it's definitely not JSON. Try removing that, first. Based on your edit, your method is expecting a bunch of parameters, and you're not sending any data at all.

Comment: That's the problem. I can't seem to find an error posted to the console. There just isn't one.

Comment: @Carson change your error function to `error: function (err) { console.log(err); }` and check the console

Comment: @Rob removing those did nothing. I am getting a message that says 'synchronous requests is depricated'

Comment: I got this 'Object {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…} '

Comment: @Carson - you need to monitor the traffic in the browser developer tools , because the request is being made , and  you are getting a response even if it is an error.  And the MVC Framework is pretty good about giving informative error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your initial post correctly, then you're saying that you get all the way to and past the return View() call in your controller, but your jQuery AJAX call says there was an error.

Your View is probably HTML, is that right to say?  If so, because in your AJAX call you've specified that you're expecting JSON, jQuery is trying to parse the response as JSON before giving it to you.  This could be the root cause of your error.

In the controller, replace the return View with:

```
return JSON(new { Test = "Hello!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And in a success handler to your AJAX call:

```
success: function(data) { alert(data.Test); }
```

If that works, then you need to either specify in your AJAX that you're going to be receiving HTML, or return your model in JSON from MVC and handle it in the success function, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: How do I tell the ajax call that it will receive HTML

Comment: Alright, so my success function comes through but the page doesn't redirect.

Comment: That's expected behaviour, in that the point of AJAX is to avoid page redirects.  You need to use that received HTML in some way in your jQuery. An example being, $('#ContentDiv').html(data).

Comment: Wow, awesome! You really know your stuff! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

In MVC GET ajax requests are blocked by default , you have to change it to Post , or allow GET

```
 return Json("string or model here"  ,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

try changing your jQuery to type 'POST' , just once and see if that fixes it.  If it does then you can try the code I provided.

You are getting a 404 because your Action Index does not have a path that accepts 0 parameters , you have all your int's set to nullable , but you have to atleast provide that parameter `searchExpression`.

Try hardcoding the url instead of Razor, and try passing it sometype of string.

```
          $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: { searchExpression : "test" },
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/Company/Index',
                success: function(data) { alert('success'); },
                error: function () { alert('error'); }
            });
```

the other answer is probably also a lot of help , I was going to reccommend also removing the `contentType` and `dataType`, they are not needed , and jQuery does a very good job at making an educated guess as to what the types are supposed to be

```
          $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: { searchExpression : "test" },
                url: '/Company/Index',
                success: function(data) { alert('success'); },
                error: function () { alert('error'); }
            });
```

Comment: This actually will only stop the request throwing an exception - however, you would be able to hit a breakpoint in the method, with or without that modification (which he in unable to)

Comment: The post got me a 404 error and the flag you recommended is invalid in return View();

Comment: The 404 is a start. Also, a messagebox shows up that says undefined

Comment: well - the 404 helps a lot .  try hardcoding the url in instead of razor Action Link and see what happens

Comment: I don't get the 404 but I do still get undefined

Comment: I added data and did exactly what you said. Still nothing. I am getting the undefined error again. Everything goes through and I can even set all parameters with the data attribute, but it still gives me undefined

Comment: I am trying to figure that out. I have no idea.

Comment: where are you seeing undefined?

Comment: In an alert after the request. I can step through my code all the way past the page rendering in a razor view. Everything is there. For some reason after it is all complete the ajax request returns undefined, or something in my code is returning undefined, and it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return HTML to your ajax call, then try this sample I just toyed with:

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Search(
        Int32? resultsPerPage,
        Int32? startingIndex,
        Int32? currentPage,
        String searchExpression)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'html',
    url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Home")',
    success : function(data){ alert(data);},
    error: function () { alert('error'); }
});
```

The key is the `dataType`. You need to set that to the type of content you expect to be returned from the ajax call, in your case you want to return HTML. Not setting that correctly will result in the `error` function being called.